# Model to Dictionary<string,string> and back

Tags: c#, reflection

I have been scouring the internet but still haven't found what I'm looking for ( what U2? ). Enough of that, what I am looking for is an intuitive way to parse a poco ( complex with Lists, nullables etc ) to a Dictionary to be stored in a key/value database and then a means to re-populate the model back. In essence I am trying to achieve what the MVC model binder does when it maps from form parameters to a model, but them be able to do the reverse as well. I have tried digging into the source but it requires all the dependencies of a controller and I dont really want that. here is some source as an example

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal? Amount { get; set; }
    public List<RowItemModel> Items { get; set; }
}

public class RowItemModel
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

So there is the model, and here is what I would like the outcome to look like :

P.S. : Note I have added a prefix for demarcation purposes in the db -> "Item."

```
Item.Name : The Name Here
Item.Amount : 0.0
Item.Items[0].Description : Description Here
Item.Items[0].Amount : 50
Item.Items[1].Description : Second Description
```

As you can see, it follows the exact same naming conventions as you would use when creating form elements for binding to a model ( using MVC ). What I am looking for is an elegant way to bind to the model from that ( dictionary ) and then to generate the dictionary from the populated model.

I have already achieved this using some really ugly string manipulation and then basic reflection combined with recursion, but it's leaving me with a bad taste in my mouth and I can't bring myself to push it to production, so any frameworks / elegant solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to achieve this? Sounds a bit like an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: My use case is the following : I need to persist the form data to the database. however the form is a dynamic one ( imagine an invoice form where you can dynamically add rows of line items ). The table structure I have to work with is a flat key/value structure so no relational model, so I figured the best means was to save the data down in the exact format as the form parameter as received by the controller, and then I obviously need to do the reverse for loading back up and editing

Answer (score 0):

I dont fully get your use case, but if all you want is your model in a dictionary, then a simple serialization and deserialization will help.

```
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var str = jss.Serialize(myObj);
var myDict = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, object>(str);
```

Of course it is not the most performant. In fact you can write a custom class that specifically handles your case. For performance use an alternative serializer like Json.NET.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I came across this solution in my searches, but the issue with this option ( apart from performance ) is that is does not generate the correct keys for the nested items that I require. ( it simply has a key for the collection name and then a json string as the collection values )

Comment: @MarkRedfern I am not sure of the output javascript serializer produces. Try Json.NET which should give you a more accurate `Dictionary<string, object>`